# Scaling individual elements of array

Tags: openmdao

I have been using the scaler variable to scale a design variable that is an array. However, I want to scale one of the elements differently from the rest. But when I input an array into the scaler variable, I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openmdao/core/problem.py", line 1642, in _calc_gradient_ln_solver
Traceback (most recent call last):
    J[item][param][:, i] *= in_scale[param]
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (48,)
```

Is it possible to add an array to the scaler? Or is there a better way to scale individual elements of an array separately rather than do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to scale an array of 48 elements, but you're providing an array of one element.  I believe your scaler needs to be either a scalar (which would equally impact the entire array) or an array of 48 elements.

For instance, assuming `foo` is a 48-element array.

```
scales = np.ones(48)
scales[0] = 2.0
driver.add_desvar('foo', lower=-10, upper=10, scaler=scales)
```

Comment: Yep that worked. It was actually a 2D array of shape (6,8) so I was passing the scaler an array of the same size. But once I flattened it, then the scaling worked. Thanks!